# Probability that at least $1$ out of $10$ random numbers between $1 \ldots 1000$ is not divisible by $7$

Tags: probability

> $10$ **different** numbers are randomly chosen from the numbers $1, 2, \ldots, 1000$. What is the probability that at least one of the chosen numbers is not divisble by $7$?

If there are $x$ numbers to choose from, there are $x/7$ numbers that are divisible by $7$. Probability of a number being divisble by $7$ is always $(x/7)/x = 1/7$.

- $A$ - at least one number is not divisble by $7$
- $\bar{A}$ - all numbers are divisible by $7$

These numbers were chosen independently so is $P(\bar{A}) = (\frac{1}{7})^{10}$ and so $P(A)=1-P(\bar{A})=1-(\frac{1}{7})^{10}$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the set $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$, there are precisely $\lfloor \frac{n}{7} \rfloor$ numbers that are divisible by $7$, not $\frac{n}{7}$.

Under the assumption that the same number can be chosen more than once, the rest seems correct.

Comment: No, 10 different numbers are chosen. But since the probability is always $1/7$ no matter how many numbers I can choose from, the answer is the same, no?

Comment: @mak: If I choose a random number between $2$ and $5$, then the probability that it is divisible by $7$ is also not $1/7$. Similarly, since $1000$ is not a multiple of $7$, here the probability is not exactly $1/7$.

Comment: @TMM: I choose the first number: 1000 numbers to choose from, probability of that number being divisble by 7 is $(1000/7)/1000=1/7$. I choose the second number: 999 numbers left to choose from, probability of that number being divisble by 7 is also $(999/7)/999=1/7$, and so on. My answer is still correct, no? (I know about rounding down the fraction)

Comment: @mak It's not quite correct. Consider the set $\{0, 1, \ldots, 10\}$. Surely, the probability of choosing a number divisible by $7$ from that set is not $1/7$, right?

Comment: @Sam There is no 0 in my set. If my answer is not correct, can you please explain how to solve? Because I have no idea how.

Comment: @mak Sorry, I meant the set $\{1, 2, \ldots, 10\}$. The point I'm trying to make is that the probability of choosing a number divisible by $7$ from that set is not $1/7$ because only one of the numbers (not $10/7$ of them) are divisible by $7$. Similarly, the probability of choosing a number divisible by $7$ from the set $\{1, 2, \ldots, 1000\}$ is not exactly $1/7$; it is $142/1000$.

Comment: @Sam OK, so the answer is $1-(floor(1/7))^2$? Even if they are different numbers?

Comment: No, you still have to account for the reduced set to select from, and the reduced number of multiples of 7 after each selection.

Comment: So, $\frac{142}{1000}\times\frac{141}{999}\times\frac{140}{998}\times...$

Comment: @mak To clarify what User58220 wrote, the probability $P(\bar{A})$ is $\frac{142}{1000} \times \frac{141}{999} \times \cdots$, and the probability $P(A)$ that you are looking for is obtained like before.

Comment: Ahh, I got it. Thanks!

Comment: But isn't $floor(999/7)=142$, so it should be $142/1000 * 142 / 999$ etc., no?

Comment: @mak Not quite. The first factor ($142/1000$) is the probability of choosing one of the $142$ multiples of $7$ as the first number, the second factor ($141/999$) is the probability of choosing one of the *remaining* $141$ multiples of $7$ from the remaining $999$ numbers as the second number, and so on. The floor operation is used just to figure out how many multiples of $7$ there are to start with.